# Accessing application.properties variables in Java SpringBoot with @Value

Tags: java, spring-boot

even though I have used it previously and it worked, currently the solution represented below doesn't work.

I intend to fetch the value and print *AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA*  strings.

**application.properties**

```
green.letters=\u001B[32m
default.letters=\u001B[0m
```

MyClass.java

```
@Component
public class MyClass{
    private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    @Value("${green.letters}")
    private String printGreen;
  
    @Value("${default.letters}")
    private String printDefault;

public final void postResultEncounter{
LOG.info(printGreen + " AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA " + printDefault);
}
```

P.S I've imported necessary dependencies/packages but the value of variables from **application.properties** is **null**

Comment: Missing `@PostConstruct` on method postResultEncounter?

Comment: show the code how you are calling this method `postResultEncounter`

Comment: MyClass myclass = new MyClass(); <<<newline>>>
myclass.postResultEncounter(//here goes an object);

Comment: You should not create component yourself - spring will do it for you. You should inject it.